# How to access datagridview in UI layer from data layer C# ?windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2012

I am trying to convert my c# windows forms project into 3 layer architecture. But,I'm not able to access datagridview in UI layer.

Can any one help me. Here is my code.

BUSINESS LOGIC CODE :

```
    BEL beobj = new BEL();
    Data dobj = new Data();
    public void show(BEL beobj)
    {
         dobj.show(beobj);
    }
```

here is UI layer code

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string dt=baobj.show(beobj);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

and finally here is my data layer code :

```
public class Data
     {
     SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMEED_KHAN\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog=Medical; Integrated security=true");        

       public DataTable show(BEL obj)
         {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stock", cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cnn.Close();
   }
   }
```

Kindly tell me how can i access datagridview1 from data layer to UI layer,Thanks

Comment: Data layer should not access UI

Comment: how can i return datatable from data layer ->business layer->UI??

Comment: *"I've converted my c# windows forms project into 3 layer architecture"* not true if you need `datagridview1` in data layer. Also check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: simply tell me how ca i access data table in UI layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your UI code as follows

```
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          DataTable dt=baobj.show(beobj);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
     }
```

Change your Business Logic code as follows

```
     public DataTable show(BEL beobj)
     {
       DataTable dtbl = dobj.show(beobj);
       return dtbl;
     }
```

Comment: Ouhhhhhh Thankss alot :) You great man....Thanks again :) It's working well..awesome work